# asp.net validation control is not working after publishing

Tags: asp.net

I have a web app using validation control such requiredvalidator. When I run it from VS 2008 directly, it worked perfectly (validated the missing input). But the moment I published it to IIS, it does not validate it anymore..

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: nothing about IIS should stop required field validator.  You sure there is no other javascript on the page?  control ids could have changed from local to IIS

Comment: Apperantly this is a comman problem with asp.net. found the solution from here: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t92775-asp-net-client-validation-not-working.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a common problem with asp.net. found the solution from here: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t92775-asp-net-client-validation-not-working.html

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug or IE8 built in web developer toolbar to see if the scripts get downloaded for the validation to run. Also check if the generated client id equals the one that is used to set up the validation (javascript at the bottom of the generated html).